# How to work with the encoder and the line sensor reading

Tags: pid

Today I am studying the operation of PID control for my robot. I have studied several articles and I managed to write a programme for my line investigator robot. In this, the error value is the value of the ideal sensor placement at the centre. For this I am using the qtr library and the readLineBlack() method;

After a few tests I managed to configure my robot to follow the line. I wanted to modernise the robot so I purchased GA12-N20 encoder motors. I had been studying encoder operation for some time and I wanted to combine the two codes. However, I can't figure out how I can combine reading the line sensors and adjusting the robot's position using the encoders? What value should I take as an error?